# Design pattern to customize possible statuses of a Character in a game

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I decided to an solid rpg-like game structure with Java to practice design patterns.

Basically there are different types of characters in my game, which are all considered to be "game objects", having some common features:

```
public abstract class Character extends GameObject {
  Status status;
  //fields, methods, etc.
}

public abstract class Monster extends Character{
  //fields, methods, etc
}

public class Hero extends Character {
  //fields, methods, etc
}
```

Status here is an enumeration:

```
public enum Status {
  NORMAL,
  BURNT,
  POISONED,
  HEALED,
  FROZEN
}
```

I would like to make my code flexible, easy-to-modify, and I would like to follow the SOLID principles using the necessary design patterns effectively.

Let's suppose I would like to customize my characters, allowing to create custom Character extensions allowing to have only certain status changes. For example I would create a Monster called

```
public class FireGolem extends Monster{...}
```

, which is unable to get damaged by heat (hence is unable to get burnt).

I have 2 ideas to do this:

1) create a Set for the class Character, in which I would specify what kind of status changes can a Character have

2) create different interfaces (Burnable, Freezable, ...) and implement them when necessary.

What do you think? Which is better and why? Is there any better and cleaner option at all?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to consider going the other way around.

Generally speaking, most characters will be burnable, freezable, etc.

So instead of creating a set for all kinds of status a character can have, create one for the characters **Immunities**.

This will allow you to handle immunities in the parent class (Character), so that when creating a new monster, all you have to do is add an immunity to it in its constructor and all will be well without having to override any methods.

Let's see how that would work in your example.

Oh but before that, short warning: I will call your status BURNING and not BURNT, just because I assume the character with that status is in fact still burning ;)

```
public abstract class Character extends GameObject {
  Status status;
  ArrayList<Status> immunities = new ArrayList<>();
  //fields, methods, etc.

  public void addImmunity(Status immunity) {
    immunities.add(immunity);
  }

  // return false if the status couldn't be set in case you want to do something
  // like show an "Immune!" message or something like that
  public boolean setStatus(Status status) {
    if (immunities.contains(status)) {
      return false;
    }
    this.status = status;
    return true;
  }
}

class FireGolem extends Monster {
  public FireGolem() {
    addImmunity(Status.BURNING);
  }
}
```

The great thing about this approach is that you will save quite a bit of memory in the long run. And you don't have to overengineer anything. Now... whether or not you're using an ArrayList or something else is of course up for debate, this is just a simple example.

Also, the setStatus method is returning a boolean as a result here. The reason I'm not throwing an exception is because I simply don't consider it one. Why wouldn't a player try to set the Fire Golem on fire? Sure, it shouldn't work, but it's still one of the expected cases. Then again, different people use different approaches and there's certainly nothing completely wrong with throwing an exception here, it's just that for me personally, it doesn't feel right. If you want more information than a simple true or false for visualization purposes, you could return more complicated objects instead, but I wanted to leave the example as simple as possible.

One more thing to add: Maybe you should also consider giving the character a status list instead of a single status because while freeze and burn might cancel each other out, I do think it's possible to be burning and poisoned at once, but that's just a matter of opinion. There are a lot of games out there that only allow a single status at once.

Comment: Incredible answer for covering both exception usage, as well as not forcing any standard design pattern where one didn't properly apply. All that was needed was a better understanding of the program requirements, with a touch of design theory for integrity.

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree with the exception part. `setStatus` is supposed only to set a status. If I want to burn that thing down, I'll do it, and I don't have to check on any return values. Having it alive afterwards, though, is quite unexpected and highly affects new moves: that's why I think throwing an exception is more appropriate...

Comment: It's also unclear who controls immunities of a character (characters themselves, or the outer world [you made it `public`]). "Generally speaking, most characters will be burnable, freezable" - It's very debatable in a world of superheroes where, conversely, all have a few *vulnerabilities*

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Exceptions should be thrown when an *unexpected* error occurs, allowing control flow to switch over to error handling. In the case of runtime exceptions, there is no error handling: it simply crashes the thread. If `FireGolem ` shouldn't be burned, attempting to set the status to burn is not unexpected behavior - it's *unwanted* behavior, which should be handled via conditions, but not unexpected behavior. A "do nothing" call would be more reasonable (simply remove the thrown exception), but both can be avoided via sturdy design.

Comment: As for exposing `addImmunity`, it could be made `protected`. However, it would make it harder to handle things like temporary immunity gained via potions or buffs.

Comment: Thank you! I am thinking of creating a Map of immunities for each class, where I can specify that my FireGolem is 90% immune to fire (or -5, thus fire would heal him). I think, with this, I can make the architecture a lot flexible. What do you think?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko 'Having it alive afterwards, though, is quite unexpected' - I strongly disagree with this. You are looking at this (maybe) from the player perspective - which shouldn't matter for your code design. If I threw an exception every time the player encounters something he doesn't expect, the game would become unplayable (or extremely boring). As a developer, the fire golem not starting to burn is very much what I expect though. In fact, I'd consider it much more of an exception if it DID start to burn.

Comment: @CsongiNagy sounds reasonable... I don't understand the -5 though ;) The 90% immunity would not be how much damage you get. 100%-90% would be the amount of damage, meaning I would expect a 105% value if you wanted to heal the golem and not a -5.

Comment: @Mark You are entirely right :) -5 makes no sense here.

Comment: Or more exactly, -5 would mean that I get even more damage than if I had 5% more damage than if I had 0 resistance.

Answer (score 2):

`FireGolem` might simply override the method `setStatus` and throw, let's say, an `IllegalArgumentException` when the given status can't be applied to its instances.

```
class FireGolem extends Monster {

    @Override
    public void setStatus(Status status) {
         if (Status.BURNT.equals(status)) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("FireGolem can't be burnt!");
         }

         super.setStatus(status);
    }

}
```

As  @Vince Emigh pointed out, it's not a pure SOLID example: preconditions shouldn't be strengthened in subclasses.

Comment: But this violates LSP by adding a pre-condition. He mentioned how he wants to abide SOLID principles. It works, but it's not SOLID.

Comment: @VinceEmigh how exactly does it violates LSP?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I see what you mean. Even though the preconditions for `super.setStatus` may be strengthened by `Status.BURNT.equals(status)`, it will not affect **the correctness of the program** which is the main idea behind this principle. Saying a program is incorrect or bad-designed just because it doesn't (completely) follow SOLID or "I'll write this just to follow SOLID" is kinda stupid. My snippet wasn't meant to be a pure SOLID demonstration, by the way. It's just a method I find reasonable.

Comment: It's not an incorrect design or anything - your solution *does* work. It's just the OP's request was to abide SOLID principles: "*I would like to follow the SOLID principles using the necessary design patterns effectively*". As for ensuring correctness via LSP, what if you have a `clearStatus(List<Monster>)` which attempted to clear all potential statuses supported at the `Monster` level? The control flow will exit, which is probably undesirable, as it would leave other monsters who have yet to be processed with their statuses still enabled. You'd have obstacles to jump to ensure correctness.

Comment: Basically, what you gave is a quick fix, which does work in this specific situation. However, it overlooks potential issues that SOLID was set in place to avoid. Since the OP requested SOLID design, it should at least be mentioned in the answer SOMEWHERE.

Comment: @VinceEmigh `monsters.forEach(m -> m.setStatus(null));`, what's the problem?

Comment: @VinceEmigh you aren't specific. What *potential issues* are you talking about?

Comment: That was apparently a bad example, sorry. Imagine a flaming meteor lands, causing nearby monsters to burn. `applyBurnTo(List<Monster>)` - does that express the idea better? `nearbyMonsters.forEach(m -> m.setStatus(Status.BURNED));` wouldn't work desirably if an exception is thrown half way through. It would be better to have `supportsStatus(Status)`, so the filter can be performed if needed, without adding a pre-condition to `setStatus`. You could then introduce a new method, at the `Monster` level, which performs the filtering before setting, preventing LSP violation.

Comment: To avoid LSP violations, `Monster` should be designed with the idea/requirement that some monsters may only support certain statuses.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I can't get how adding a method `supportsStatus(Status)` could improve the situation. The method itself a precondition (assuming Monster's `supportsStatus` returns true, how would you override the method without strengthening its condition?). Not to mention, you're now forcing the caller to constantly check this method before calling others.

Comment: Yes, the method is a pre-condition. The difference is where the pre-condition exists: who is aware of the pre-condition. By defining it in `Monster`, systems built around `Monster` will be aware of it, allowing those systems to account for such. By defining the pre-condition in the subtype, systems built around `Monster` are not aware of the pre-condition. Thus, if someone wrote a system the uses `Monster`, they'd have no idea the pre-condition exists unless they looked through all the subtypes - developing a system for `Monster` would require subtype awareness. Create a chat for elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look at the [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)?

Basically, each state would be a class, and they all have the same base class. 
Then you'll have a context (e.g. your character), where it holds the current state and uses it.

You can, of course, control if a state X can turn into state Y and so on, since each state holds a reference to its context.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not **extend** in order to **limit** capabilities / functionalities. That violates [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which is part of SOLID which you said you want to use.

In your particular case you first say **every** `Character` can have one of those statuses and then you try to introduce a character that can not have given status.

My first thought (I can't claim a solution without knowing all the details) about this particular case is to follow the [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and introduce interfaces that provide `isBurnt`, `isFrozen`, ... respectively. I may then aggregate those into say `Fragile` interface if most `Character`s should implement all. It is also possible to have say `FragileCharacter` abstract class with the common logic.

Comment: looks like a lot of `instanceof` and casts will be introduced

Comment: or you would have to work with each type separately, which really isn't a good option

Comment: That depends on how the rest of the architecture looks like. That's why I stated "I can't claim a solution without knowing all the details"

Comment: I have no idea as well, just curious... Imagine you have a `Character` and you need to change its status to `BURNT`, would you use `instanceof` on it?

Comment: Well we are deep into the assumptions land here ;) Anything we say may or may not be relevant. That said I can imagine an "action" say `setOnFire (Burnable ...)` instead of `setOnFire (Character ...)` which gives you nice safeguards (you can't set on fire what does not burn) at compile time. The opposite (checking if `Character` can be in given status and react with exception if not) only works at run time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your scope is something more than a toy project, so follow SOLID principe here is a need, not only an execise. Otherwise you can do with your approach with no problem at all.

My pick is not to use inheritance, but instead encapsulation, because you have better modularity in your code and is more maintanable. [For reference on digging in this discussion, here see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

So in your case avoid to have a GameObject, extend with Character then extend with Monster and hero, because every little change in GameObject will have repercussions in every entity of your game.

You could use another approach: Entity Component System ([reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941953/the-composite-pattern-entity-system-and-traditional-oop) and [here](http://entity-systems.wikidot.com/).

So in your case you will:

- basic components: position, movement, graphic
- create basic systems: for example system that take all entities with a graphic component and display on screen
- build entity based on a template: hero, monster

For another reference on experience using it [see here](https://blog.gemserk.com/2017/12/27/how-we-used-entity-component-system-ecs-approach-at-gemserk-12/)

**Note**: Ecs are used by big names too, like Unity